# Does the "for" loop in C require a "{}" after it?

Tags: c, for-loop, token, grammar

I had this code in my program:

```
if (primeiro != atual){                        
                    for (i = 0; i < atual -> numeroChaves; i++) 
                    // comment
}
```

And I was receiving the following error:

```
d8641900: In function 'printaArvore':
d8641900:130:7: error: expected expression before '}' token
       }
       ^
```

So I made the following change in the code:

```
if (primeiro != atual){                        
                        for (i = 0; i < atual -> numeroChaves; i++){}
                        // comment
    }
```

and it runned smoothly.

My doubt is: is it some problem with my code, or it is a rule applied in all cases?

The funny part is that, in other part of my code, I have a similar situation (no "{}" after the for loop), but after it I have a line with a valid command, and it runs perfectly.

Comment: It needs *something*: either braces, or a line of content

Comment: Any loop or test requires **something** after it. The same rules apply. If no braces are provided, the next line alone is executed. If braces are provided, then all within the braces are executed.

Comment: @sapi Note the empty statement `;` qualifies as something. So `for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i);` is valid, and does nothing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"for" loop in C needs one statement after it.

If you need several statements, then you can enclose them with `{` and `}`.
(Of course, you can also enclose zero or one statement.)

And `;` can represent an empty statement.

So any of the followings are correct.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {}
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) function_that_do_nothing();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 1;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) function_that_do_something();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) just_a_statement;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { statements... }
```

Additionally,

```
for (initialization; condition; statement)
    one_statement;
```

cannot be separated, so the followings are equal.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        a_statement;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        a_statement;
}

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        a_statement;
    }
}
```

The same thing goes for `if` or `while`.

Comment: Thanks! So, in the caseof "for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 1;" , a number is understood as as statement? Curious!

Comment: `1;` is a statement that does nothing like `true;`, `false;`, or `0;`. Also, `i = i;` is a statement that does nothing in effect (but the CPU can take a very short time at this statement if the compiler does not abandon this statement).

Comment: Yes, any expression can be a statement. But nothing followed by a semicolon is also a statement.

Comment: In the specific case of a loop, my personal favorite is `for (...) continue;` I dislike `for (..);` as I find myself not noticing the bare semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

No, the braces aren't required, but they're a good idea.

The syntax of a `for` statement is:

**`for`** ( *expression*<sub>opt</sub> ; *expression*<sub>opt</sub> ; *expression*<sub>opt</sub> ) *statement*

(You can also replace the first "*expression*<sub>opt</sub> ;" with a declaration, but that's not important here.)

The important part is the *statement* at the end. A `for` statement requires exactly one statement as part of it.

That can be any kind of statement, including a null statement (consisting of a single semicolon) or a *block*, also known as a *compound statement*.

A compound statement consists of an opening `{`, followed by zero or more declarations and statements, followed by a closing `}`.

So you can write:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
     printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

but the braces are part of the syntax of the compound statement, *not* of the `for` statement. The above may also be written as:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
     printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

or even:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) printf("i = %d\n", i);
```

As a matter of style, I personally prefer to *always* use a compound statement as the controlled statement of a `for` (or `if`, or `while`, etc.), because (a) it's easier to be consistent, and (b) it's more maintainable; if I want to add a second statement before or after the `printf`, then the braces are already there.

One thing to watch out for: if you accidentally write:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++);  /* extra semicolon */
{
     printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

that's still perfectly legal -- but `for` controls only the empty statement consisting of that stray semicolon; the block following it is separate, and will be executed exactly once rather than 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

The braces aren't *strictly* necessary; what you need is at exactly one (possibly empty) statement following the `for`. You can accomplish this by putting just a semi-colon, terminating an empty statement:

```
// It's a little more readable to put the semicolon on a line by itself
for (i=0; i<atual->numerChaves; i++)
;
```

or, as you did, by including an empty *compound* statement consisting of empty braces.

Comment: You need *exactly* one (possibly null) statement.